# SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE column = $variable

Tags: php, select, where-clause

I'm trying to retrieve the id number of a record to use as a variable elsewhere. I only want the id from a record that has a particular value in another column. here is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM order WHERE orderNumber = '$orderNumber'") or die (mysql_error());
$id = $result;
```

When I test I get: SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server versi0on for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE orderNumber = '5b0ea3'

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that the actual query and error message that you're getting?

Comment: A good idea would be not to change your fields and variable names when asking the question

Comment: The mysql_* methods are deprecated, I recommend switching to either mysqli or PDO, and `$variable` should be sanitised before being put into a query. What does the final query look like if you echo it before running it?

Comment: This is the code with all the info in it: 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM order WHERE orderNumber = '$orderNumber'") or die (mysql_error());
$id = $result;

And error message:
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order WHERE orderNumber = '5b0ea3'

Sorry about that

Comment: Without seeing your actual column and table names, I can only guess that maybe you have used a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in place of `table_name`.

Comment: After the edit - sure enough, `ORDER` is a reserved keyword. Please always use your real code in the first place...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM order WHERE orderNumber = '$orderNumber'
```

ORDER is a reserver word in SQL; I'd recommend you change the name of the table to something else.

If you really can't, then you can escape column and table names with backticks:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `order` WHERE `orderNumber` = '$orderNumber'
```

Or

```
SELECT `id` FROM `order` WHERE `orderNumber` = '".$orderNumber."'
```

And also see the comments about stopping using `mysqli_` functions - they're insecure, and being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ORDER` is a reserved word, you must use backticks on your sql query. And after that use the [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) in order to get the id.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `order` WHERE `orderNumber` = '$orderNumber'") or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$id = $row['id'];
```

On the other hand, you should be using `PDO` or `Mysqli`, the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and considered a bad practice.

If you plan on keep using `mysql_query`, at least make sure to sanitize the `$orderNumber` variable with [mysql_real_escape_String](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT `id` FROM `order` WHERE `orderNumber` = '$orderNumber'");
```

as you see you must include $connection.

Comment: This is not right for the `mysql` version of this function. The problem was in fact what was pointed by the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Built using custom database class with query function, but the SQL query works

```
$id = 1;
$database->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_post WHERE post_id = '$id'");
```